# How can I pass a class object from Activity to a class to be able to call its methods?

Tags: android, object, android-activity, data-transfer-objects, transmitfile

I need to create an `object` of the `BLE` class in the Activity, in `onCreate`, I tried to implement it with `Parcel` (passing the object via Intent), but I have an application **crash** from it.

As it turned out, the reason was that in the BLE class when I accept The content:

```
mDeviceListAdapter = getEnableIntent().getParcelableExtra("lVAdapter");
mDeviceListAdapter == null
```

Later I learned that the Intent serves to transfer data only in the onCreate from one Activity to another.

Please tell me how I can transfer objects of the created classes to other classes (not Activity). Thankful in advance.

Comment: Depends what's that second class of yours. If is a `fragment` that gets attached to your `activity` then you could make a public method inside activity and call it in fragment either by passing activity instance to fragment or just call `getActivity().yourPublicMethod();` . Make sure to check `getActivity()` before

Comment: Is there any specific reason of not making class object Singleton or just static?

Comment: No, BLE is an ordinary class (not a fragment), in which is part of the logic of my application responsible for Bluetooth